# Images loading from server on every page load

Tags: caching, media, theming

I am using the views flexslider with same images on every page but when ever we go from one page to another or come back to the previously browse page it take a time to load images.

It seems like views always loads the images from the server. Is there a way those images could appear instantly on every page. May be loading the images through browser cache ??

EDIT

**The problem was actually because of Adaptive Image module I have turned that off and the images are loading normally now.**

Comment: Loading the images through browser cache can be configured only through apache config, there is nothing to do inside Drupal. If the module loads the image from server on every page load, submit a bug report in modules page in drupal.org.

Comment: Is this using a public or private file system?

Comment: @mikeytown2 its using public file system

Comment: I think I have found the culprit. Actually I was using Adaptive Image that was causing images to reload on every page. Any idea how can we overcome the issue while using adaptive image module ??

Comment: You can enable caching for views displays in views display settings itself.

Comment: I already done that but that make no difference. As I have mentioned in my comment that the problem was actually because of Adaptive Image module I have turned that off and the images are loading normally now.

Comment: Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching problem was not with the views, it was actually [Adaptive Image](https://drupal.org/project/adaptive_image) module which was causing the frustrating image reload issue.

After trying several caching options, I disabled the Adaptive Styles and use normal image styles and the issue was resolved.

For adaptive images I am now using [Adaptive Image Styles](https://drupal.org/project/ais) and it is working fine. Though this require some modifications in .htaccess file but that is acceptable.